# Upload pdf/doc not working in TAB/IPad

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, docx

I'm creating a form with upload option which will be accessible in Desktop and tablets.

I'm trying to upload jpg/pdf/doc/docx file in onchange property, everything seems to work properly in desktop but in tablets .jpg works fine but if try to upload pdf/doc getting  **"file moved or deleted"** error

```
upload_field.form.action = "upload-documents.php";
upload_field.form.target = 'upload_iframe';
upload_field.form.submit();
```

Note : file size not more than 500kb

Comment: Can you edit the question and share your php-code for the uploading part?

Comment: @Myonara the above mentioned issue had nothing to do with code. It was specific to Tab device. Thanks!!!